# Por que algumas perguntas recebem 1 voto positivo depois de alguns minutos?

Tags: debate, perguntas, votos

Nesses meses de atividade no SOpt tenho notado que algumas perguntas recebem +1 depois de um certo tempo (geralmente alguns minutos após serem postadas) e ficam nesse 1.

Sem entrar no mérito se a pergunta é boa ou ruim (algumas dessas perguntas, ao meu ver muito ruins, com muito código, sem objetividade, pouca clareza ou aplicações esquisitas que o AP quer fazer etc.) elas recebem o seu +1. E essas perguntas, muitas vezes, passam horas ou dias (ou pra sempre) sem nenhum interesse da comunidade, não apresentam comentários ou respostas, mas o voto positivo está lá, como citei antes.

Isso me suscitou uma dúvida: o sistema de alguma forma vota +1 na pergunta por algum critério automático ou esse voto só pode ter sido dado por algum usuário? Ou seja, é possível que o site tenha um robô que avalia a pergunta, acha válida por algum algorítimo, e vota +1 na pergunta? Ou alguém sabe a explicação para esse comportamento?

Comment: Pode ser também alguém atrás de uma medalha e saiu dando upvote loucamente (tem uma medalha se não me engano)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

É quase impossível responder isso ao certo, mesmo que fosse um caso específico teria que analisar coisas que não temos como saber, nem a SE conseguiria isso, embora ela poderia espionar o comportamento dos usuários que poderia dar um palpite embasado. No geral assim não dá.

Pode-se, claro, especular o que pode acontecer:

- ninguém viu antes
- pessoa certa ainda não viu
- alguém viu, poderia ter votado, mas não quis votar antes por milhões de motivos possíveis
- a pessoa está esperando algo melhorar para poder votar, e muitos casos ela pode mudar de ideia e votar mesmo não tende melhorado
- está esperando se não rolar lambança (eu falo muito isso, porque rola...)
- a pessoa que viu e pode votar até criteriosamente não quis votar porque não gosta da pessoa que postou e tem que esperar vir alguém que não tenha essa tendenciosidade. Tem muito disso aqui no site.

Não coloquei os casos mais esotéricos, mas multiplique esses listas por 1000 e está mais perto, mas ainda longe do total de motivos que pode ocorrer.

Existe outro fenômeno que é ficar um tempo sem votos, aí depois que sai o primeiro vem uma enxurrada. A pessoa não tem critério, não entende do assunto, ou está em dúvida e precisa da validação de outra pessoa, quando ela vem, o voto sai, aí vem outros, e vem o "maria vai com as outras" clássico que vota no que já está votado, sem nenhuma preocupação. Votos errados são dados o tempo todo, mas é difícil coibir, até mesmo porque é difícil determinar com certeza com ele ocorreu.

Um exemplo do que ocorre com votos: [O que é linguagem de programação, IDE e compilador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101).

Esta pergunta rapidamente recebeu *likes*, digo, votos, até porque ela é curiosa, fácil de ler e saber se é boa. Minha resposta nela foi longa então demorou. A maioria das pessoas que deram *like* nela não voltaram para ver as respostas, provavelmente por falha do sistema em não incentivar a pessoa voltar lá. A resposta ficou com menos votos. Claro que alguns podem ter deixado de votar porque ela é longa e apessoa não quer ler. EU poderia ter feito um TL;DR, mas já mostra que era um *like* mesmo, não era algo importante para a pessoa. Também pode ser que a pessoa não gostou da resposta para votar, normal. O fato é que depois de um tempo a pergunta foi recebendo votos e a resposta não muito provavelmente porque se a resposta tem menos votos pode ter alguma coisa ruim nela. A pessoa não vota pelo conteúdo, só vota. Essa [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/101) o pessoal vota sempre nas pergunta e na resposta, mesmo sendo longa, mesmo tendo algo mais difícil de avaliar se está certa ou não, porque a resposta nunca ficou muito atrás da pergunta.

tem muitos fenômenos que diminui a credibilidade dos votos. Outro exemplo: eu tenho um monte de resposta que tem a aceitação e muitas vezes só o voto do AP, tenho medo dessas porque pode ter algo errado e eu não ter percebido, a única pessoa que avaliou e achou que é bom é quem perguntou que é uma pessoa que provavelmente não entende do assunto. Mas me orgulho de ter a maioria das minhas respostas avaliadas por muitas pessoas.

Outra questão na pergunta que nada tem a ver com o título é sobre a pessoa votar +1 em pergunta ruim. Talvez fosse isso que queria perguntas mesmo.

O mais provável é que a pessoa achou interessante, quer ver uma resposta ali, ou coisa parecida, mas ela não entende nada daquilo. Tem muito voto assim e é ruim porque ele tem mais a ver com *like*. A SE já demonstrou que não se interessa em exigir mais critério, dar mais explicação do que significa os triângulos para cima e para baixo do lado esquerdo. As pessoas não costumam votar para classificar o conteúdo e incentivar o bom.

Existem outras possibilidades, como retribuição por algo que o usuário fez. Usuários populares ou populistas tendem a receber esse "boi". Mas também usuários experientes não costumam fazer perguntas ruins, então vale mais pra usuários "começando" no site.

Nem falei do voto a esmo que o cara dá só pra ganhar medalha, ou o voto de sacanagem, quase vandalismo, ou fraude também conhecida "ação entre amigos" que pode ser feito algo se ficar claro e estiver prejudicando a comunidade.

O sistema só vota em algo se houver sinalização de VLQ (Qualidade muito baixa) que seja aceita e atenda alguns outros critérios. Então não há voto positivo pelo Comunidade ou outro mecanismo.

Já vi alguma de gente que deveria cuidar do site votar quase aleatoriamente para provocar os usuários que não gostam disto, o que é terrível de saber que isto ocorria, não se se isso conta como "voto automático do sistema".

Eu adoraria que tivesse um robô que avalizasse um monte de coisa e ajudasse moderar o site, mesmo que não de forma definitiva, mas como auxiliar. O Comunidade sinaliza sozinho certas postagens como VLQ, o que muitas vezes é recusado já que a resposta só era curta. Em era de AI precisa ter algo que realmente use ML para melhorar nossa UX que é o que importa de fato.

Comment: Considerando que muitos votos são likes ñ tem pq ter comentário, o q o sujeito postará? "mee too", "gostei", "é isso aí", "parabéns pela pergunta"? Em geral é melhor não ter isso mesmo. Novamente, não tem como saber o que o votando pensa, inclusive pode ser algo diferente em cada vez. Pra conseguir votos tem um pouco a ver com conquistar corações e mentes, Tem coisa boa q ñ vai pra frente e coisa ruim que vai, e depende muito do momento da postagem, quem vê primeiro, a coisa vai longe... Para falar a verdade sem maiores informações, nem sei se isso é importante de fato (fora o robô) é assim...

Comment: Não, não peguei, é confuso, tanto que começou repetir as mesmas coisas no comentário, parece nem você ter entendido muito bem o que está falando, mas é mais um "deixa pra lá", se não era importe deixe pra lá antes de postar.

Comment: Não o farei, se postou assuma a sua responsabilidade como nunca faz, e continua apagando o que fez de errado.